# Pass parameters from js.erb file to js file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I've initiated `ajax call` from `/assets/js/myfile.js` which hits the controller and in my controller action i've

`@myVar = ModelClass.create(params)
 respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  format.html
end`

so that i could use the my `myaction.js.erb` file functionalities . which i have as below
`$("#box_div").append('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "box.html.erb") %>');`

point to remember is that i can access `@myVar` variable here in `js.erb` file and showing data good . After this point `partial view` is rendered and all the partial tags/values is posted back in `ajax success function` . which looks like a small html page due to rendering of partial . (all is normal behavior.
 Now what i want is that i wanna pass a specific parameter back like id : <%= @myVar.id%>

**my /assets/js/myfile.js**

`$.post("/conversations", { sender_id: sender_id, recipient_id: recipient_id }, function (data) {
**//I want id value sent back from js.erb file here**
   console.log(data);
         });`

Comment: you want to pass @myVar.id to partial?

Comment: let me update my question

Comment: @sadaf2605 read again my updated portion specifically

Comment: you can used hidden field value in js and update particular value in js.erb file with ` <%= @myVar.id%>`

Comment: @VishalJAIN dear that doesn't make sense to me , can you give an example ?

Comment: @ImranNaqvi added in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way just created rough skeleton:

**myfile.js**

```
myvar_id = $("#myvar").val();
$.post("/conversations", { sender_id: sender_id, recipient_id: recipient_id }, function (data) {
//I want id value sent back from js.erb file here
   console.log(data);
});
```

**Js.erb**

```
$("#box_div").append('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "box.html.erb") %>');
```

**_box.html.erb**

```
 <input type="hidden" id="myvar" value="<%= @myvar.id %>">
```

Comment: hmm that's clear now . and seems to be fine .I'll check it and tell you a bit latter